# Why does my SQL agent job keep failing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL agent job that just runs a basic query on a schedule. It updates info based on the query shown.

```
USE DB
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @rcount AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @startDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME) 
SET @endDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME) 
--*********************************************************
-- *Run Query
--*********************************************************
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.field1 = 'ZPR' +  Left(Table1.field1,6),
    Table1.field2 = '0',
    Table1.field3 = '0' 
WHERE  Table1.GUID IN (SELECT GUID FROM Table1 T2 
    WHERE T2.Date >= @startDate 
        AND T2.Date <= @endDate 
        AND   T2.complete = 0)
    AND Table1.co IN (SELECT co FROM VIEW('ZERO')) 
SELECT @rcount = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 'row(s) affected by UPDATE';
--*********************************************************
--* Print Results
--*********************************************************
DECLARE @eSubject varchar(250)
DECLARE @emailTo varchar(250)
SET @eSubject = 'Number of rows updated'   
SET @emailTo = 'me@me.com' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@emailTo,
    @subject = @eSubject,
    @body = @rcount,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

The job runs perfectly when there isn't any updates done but fails whenever there is. The user that this job is ran under has read and write access. The error that I get is "The string or the binary data would be truncated [sql220001] [error 8152]". I'm not sure why it keeps failing and any help would be amazing!

********************UPDATE************

I'm going crazy here. It fails as a scheduled job but runs perfectly under any other user as a straight query. The fields are as such:

Table1.field1 = PK length of 10
Table1.field2 = bit length of 1
Table1.field3 = bit length of 1

no matter what I try or do the SQL job fails with the same error but it is making me nuts that I can run the query by itself and it works flawlessly.

Comment: What is the definition of Table1.field? Sound like it's not big enough to hold the results of 'ZPR' + Left(Table1.field,7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing @rcount to `varchar(50)`.  I **think** that's the issue.

**EDIT:**

Since my first suggestion didn't solve your issue, look for triggers on your table.  It could also give you that error if a trigger is being run that is trying to put, say, 50 characters into a varchar(25) field.

You can get around this error in the future by, before any set command (or select @var = [insert data here]), do a `LEFT([insert data here], #)`  (# being the maximum length of that field).

Comment: I have made that adjustment and still get the same issue.

Comment: @MattH @@rowcount would be on average 1 or 2 rows. On heavy days the most it would be is like 5 - 10 rows. There are no triggers at all on this database and using LEFT(field,#) doesn't seem to have any affect on the job finishing.

Comment: @MattH i found out that there is indeed a trigger on the table that handles log changes. since the field change is being made by 'microsoft sql server 2008 sql agent' it's too long of a field to go into the changed by field on the table for log changes. any ideas?

Comment: @BSanders - You could modify the trigger to use a case statement when inserting into the "changed by" field.  If you give me some information on the trigger (or some code of the trigger) I will gladly modify my answer to include a proposed [CASE-WHEN-THEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

Comment: @BSanders - Just checking to see if you got your trigger working properly now, or if you need any more assistance with it?

Comment: unfortunately due to corporate restrictions I'm unable to change the trigger. what I have done to make to this work is I have written a program that executes this and it works. Since I think you were the closest to the answer I will award you the bounty. Thank you!

Comment: @BSanders - Glad you got a workaround in place!  Thanks for the bounty.  Always glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are some triggers set on the Table1 causing the issue? If there are you should check the code of those as well.

Comment: I looked into it and there are no triggers.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `@rcount` is set to a max size of `10`. e.g. `VARCHAR(10)`.

However you will notice at the end of your show SQL you have:

```
SELECT @rcount = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 'row(s) affected by UPDATE';
```

this is at least double the maximum size.  You might try increasing `@rcount` to a larger `VARCHAR`.

-RosSQL

Answer (score 2):

Disect the query.  Add one statement to the run each time to make sure you know *exactly* which bit it is complaining about.  Make sure you run it using the credentials the job will be using.

First

```
USE DB
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @rcount AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @startDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME) 
SET @endDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME)
```

Then

```
USE DB
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @rcount AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @startDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME) 
SET @endDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME) 
--*********************************************************
-- *Run Query
--*********************************************************
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.field1 = 'ZPR' +  Left(Table1.field1,6),
    Table1.field2 = '0',
    Table1.field3 = '0' 
WHERE  Table1.GUID IN (SELECT GUID FROM Table1 T2 
    WHERE T2.Date >= @startDate 
        AND T2.Date <= @endDate 
        AND   T2.complete = 0)
    AND Table1.co IN (SELECT co FROM VIEW('ZERO'))
```

etc. until you know precisely which part throws the exception.

I'm assuming it will be the `UPDATE Table1` statement.  Start dissecting that.  Run it once updating only field1, then field1 and field2 etc.  Similarly in your subselect - remove all clauses and add them back, one at a time, until it breaks.

My best guess - you and the job-running credentials have different default schema.  The optimiser is using a different set of objects for you and for the job.  My guess is your Table1.field1 is a different length to the job's Table1.field1.  The fix is to prefix your object reference with the schema i.e. `UPDATE dbo.Table1`.  It is best practice to this in *every* statement.

As an aside, field2 and field3 are defined as bit but you are setting them to a char(1).  Remove the quotes and save an implicit type convertion.  `WHERE T2.Date >= @startDate AND T2.Date <= @endDate` would look nicer as `WHERE T2.Date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `field2` and `field3` to `0` or `cast(0 as bit)` instead of `'0'`?

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out this statement in your job and see if this works. From what you have describe in your edit it seems that definition and assignments are ok.

```
  SELECT @rcount = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 'row(s) affected by UPDATE';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some small adjustments that may cause issues or confuse SQL.  I also assume that Field3 is in fact numeric (int, etc.).  Also confirm the output of the View('zero') is numeric or is not causing the truncate:

```
USE database
DECLARE @startDate AS DATE
DECLARE @endDate AS DATE
DECLARE @rcount AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @startDate = GETDATE()
SET @endDate = GETDATE()
--*********************************************************
--* Query
--*********************************************************
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.field = 'ZPR' +  Left(isnull(Table1.field,''), 7)
WHERE  Table1.field2 IN (SELECT left(isnull(field,''),10) FROM Table2 T2 
    WHERE T2.Date >= @startDate 
        AND T2.Date <= @endDate 
        AND   T2.field3 = 0)
    AND Table1.field3 IN (SELECT field FROM VIEW('ZERO')) 
SELECT @rcount = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 'row(s) affected by UPDATE';
--*********************************************************
--* Print Results
--*********************************************************
DECLARE @eSubject varchar(250)
DECLARE @emailTo varchar(250)
SET @eSubject = 'here is your email'   
SET @emailTo = 'me@me.com' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@emailTo,
    @subject = @eSubject,
    @body = @rcount,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: The fields that you suggested the changes to are both PK, not null. I still tried the changes and the job still fails.

Comment: It could be a schema issue.  Add dbo. in front of all the table references to make sure it is looking at the correct schema tables.  I have been there..